# I am having an issue where I am unable to set objectA = objectB without getting all empty properties on objectA

Tags: c#, linq, object

I have tried several methods, 3 can be seen in the code below, the other was setting each property on the customer.ReconnectStats = to the corresponding property on the rs object. The fields on the rs object **are** populated, but the values are never copied to the customer.ReconnectStats. The "ref" parameter modifier was just added as another test in my last attempt. The code for the loading and iterating through the reader has been removed and isn't relevant. The linq attempt is the original and my preferred method.

```
 private void AddReconnectStatus(ref Customer customer)
        {
            //we'll only load this collection once per customer reload
            if (_reconnectStatuses == null)
            {
                SqlConnection connection = null;
                SqlCommand cmd = null;
                IDataReader reader = null;

               //loading of _reconnectStatuses occurs here, but only during the first call to this                  method
            }

            //var match = _reconnectStatuses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CustomerID == customer.CustomerNumber.Trim() && a.SONumber == customer.SONumber.Trim());
            //customer.ReconnectStats = match;

            foreach (var rs in _reconnectStatuses)
            {
                if (rs.CustomerID == customer.CustomerNumber.Trim() && rs.SONumber == customer.SONumber.Trim())
                {
                    //customer.ReconnectStats = rs;
                    customer.ReconnectStats = new ReconnectStatus()
                    {
                        SONumber = rs.SONumber.Trim(),
                        CustomerID = rs.CustomerID.Trim(),
                        SentToTechID = rs.SentToTechID.Trim(),
                        ReconnectID = rs.ReconnectID,
                        DateSent = rs.DateSent.Trim(),
                        SentByUser = rs.SentByUser.Trim(),
                        SentToTechEmail = rs.SentToTechEmail.Trim()
                    };
                    break;
                }
            }
        }




internal class ReconnectStatus : ViewModelBase
    {
        internal int ReconnectID { get; set; }
        internal string CustomerID { get; set; }

        private String _SentByUser = string.Empty;
        public String SentByUser
        {
            get
            { return _SentByUser ?? string.Empty; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _SentByUser)
                {
                    _SentByUser = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private String _SentToTechID = string.Empty;
        public String SentToTechID
        {
            get
            { return _SentToTechID ?? string.Empty; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _SentToTechID)
                {
                    _SentToTechID = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private String _SentToTechEmail = string.Empty;
        public String SentToTechEmail
        {
            get
            { return _SentToTechEmail ?? string.Empty; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _SentToTechEmail)
                {
                    _SentToTechEmail = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private String _DateSent = string.Empty;
        public String DateSent
        {
            get
            { return _DateSent ?? string.Empty; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _DateSent)
                {
                    _DateSent = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private String _SONumber = string.Empty;
        public String SONumber
        {
            get
            { return _SONumber ?? string.Empty; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _SONumber)
                {
                    _SONumber = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

    }



//property on Customer

private ReconnectStatus _ReconnectStats = new ReconnectStatus();
        public ReconnectStatus ReconnectStats
        {
            get
            { return _ReconnectStats = new ReconnectStatus(); }
            set
            {
                if (value != _ReconnectStats)
                {
                    _ReconnectStats = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong at first glance - have you run it in the debugger to see if the columns in `rs` have data? Does `customer.ReconnectStatus` have non-default code in the setter that might not be settings the value property? Are you certain that a match is being found? (comparing numbers that are actually strings can be tricky if there is whitespace)

Comment: Can you share a definition for the `Customer` and `ReconnectStats` types?  Maybe there's some problem with the  `customer.ReconnectStatus` setter.  We're more likely to be able to help you if you can share code that completely reproduces the problem -- i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: I see the problem. Where did that "= New ReconnectStatus()" come from? It came from a bad snippet I think.

Comment: I didn't look at the property until I posted it here. My properties are almost always identical in structure, or at least very close. That was a sloppy error that I should have caught. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also note that `NotifyPropertyChanged` will only fire if you set the value of the property to a _new_ value. If the property returns a reference to a object and you change one of the properties of that object, `NotifyPropertyChanged` will not fire (unless it's used on the object's properties also, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ReconnectStatus.get` getter is broken.  You allocate a new `ReconnectStatus` every time:

```
get
{ return _ReconnectStats = new ReconnectStatus(); }
```

You only want to allocate a new `_ReconnectStats` if the current value is null:

```
get { return _ReconnectStats ?? (_ReconnectStats = new ReconnectStatus()); }
```